# Installing several RPMs with custom install flags

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to do the initial work to get our dev shop to start using vagrant + puppet during development.  At this stage in my puppet manifest development, I need to install several RPMs that are available via an internal http server (not a repo) with very specific flags ('--nodeps').

So, here's an example of what I need to install:

```
http://1.2.3.4/bar/package1.rpm
http://1.2.3.4/bar/package2.rpm
http://1.2.3.4/bar/package3.rpm
```

I would normally install them in this way:

```
rpm --install --nodeps ${rpm_uri}
```

I would *like* to be able to do something like this

```
$custom_rpms = [
    'http://1.2.3.4/bar/package1.rpm',
    'http://1.2.3.4/bar/package2.rpm',
    'http://1.2.3.4/bar/package3.rpm',
]

# edit:  just realized I was instantiating the parameterized
#        class wrong.  :) 
class { 'custom_package': package_file => $custom_rpms }
```

With this module

```
# modules/company_packages/manifests/init.pp
define company_package($package_file) {
    exec { "/bin/rpm  --install --nodeps ${package_file} --nodeps" }
}
```

But, I'm not sure if that's right.  Can some of you puppet masters (no pun intended) school me on how this should be done?

Answer (score 3):

You may have already worked around this by now, but if not.

Using a repository is the preferred method as it will autoresolve all the dependancies, but it that's not available you can try the following. (I'm using epel as an example rpm)

```
package {"epel-release":
  provider=>rpm,
  ensure=>installed,
  install_options => ['--nodeps'],
  source=>"http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm",
}
```

It used to be that 'install_options ' was only supported in windows.
It appears that it is now supported in linux.
If there is sequence that would be helpful, add "require=Package["package3.rpm"]," to sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Randm over irc.freenode.net#puppet

> Create or use an existing repo and install them with yum so that it resolves the dependencies for you.